Every tight $\tau$-additive finite measure is Radon
According to the 7.2.2 Theorem of the book "Measure Theory" written by V.I. Bogachev, every tight $\tau$-additive finite measure is Radon. The proof says: "The restrictions of a $\tau$-additive measure to all compact subspaces are Radon". That theorem also says that a $\tau$-additive finite measure on a compact Hausdorff space is Radon, so I tried to use this fact. However, I couldn't prove that the restriction of a $\tau$-additive measure to a compact subspace is also $\tau$-additive.
Below I'll recall some definitions:

A Borel finite measure $\mu$ on a topological space $X$ is called Radon if for all $B$ in $\mathcal{B}(X)$ and $\varepsilon >0$, there exists a compact set $K\subseteq B$ such that $\mu (B\setminus K)<\varepsilon$.
A Borel measure $\mu$ on a topological space $X$ is called tight if for all $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a compact $K\subseteq X$ such that $\mu (X\setminus K)<\varepsilon $.
A Borel measure $\mu$ on a topological space $X$ is called $\tau$-additive if for every increasing net of open sets $(U_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ in $X$, one has the equality $\mu (\cup _{\lambda\in\Lambda}U_\lambda )=\lim_{\lambda}\mu (U_\lambda)$.


My question is: how can I prove that every tight $\tau$-additive finite measure on a Hausdorff space is also Radon?

I know that given a closed set $C\subseteq X$ and $\tau$-additive measure $\mu :\mathfrak{B}(X)\to \mathbb{R}$, the measure $\mu _C:\mathfrak{B}(X)\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\mu _C(E):=\mu (E\cap C)$ is $\tau$-additive w.r.t. topology of $X$. However, I don't know if the restriction $\mu|_{\mathfrak{B}(F)}$ is $\tau$-additive w.r.t. subspace topology of $F$.

It seems that the part you're having trouble with is proving that the restriction of a bounded $\tau$-additive Borel measure to a Borel subset is $\tau$-additive (and you can follow the rest of Bogachev's proof once you know this). If you want to give it one last try, do so before crossing the following line.

Let $X$ be a topological space, $\mu$ a bounded $\tau$-additive Borel measure on $X$, $S$ a Borel subset of $X$ and define $\nu$ to be the restriction of $\mu$ to $S$. Suppose for a contradiction that $\nu$ is not $\tau$-additive, so there exists a directed family $\mathcal{U}$ of $S$-open sets such that:
$$
\sup_{U \in \mathcal{U}} \nu(U) < \nu\left(\bigcup \mathcal{U}\right).
$$
For convenience, we write $U' = \bigcup \mathcal{U}$, and observe that the above implies there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $U \in \mathcal{U}$, $\nu(U' \setminus U) = \nu(U') - \nu(U) \geq \epsilon$.
To relate this back to the $\tau$-additivity of $\mu$, define
$$
\mathcal{V} = \{ V \subseteq X \mid V \text{ open and } V \cap S \in \mathcal{U} \}
$$
i.e. the set of open subsets of $X$ that restrict to elements of $\mathcal{U}$, and define $V' = \bigcup \mathcal{V}$. It is easily proved that $\mathcal{V}$ is directed and $V' \cap S = U'$. By $\tau$-additivity, there exists $V \in \mathcal{V}$ such that $\mu(V') - \mu(V) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.
Now, intuitively, we have reached a contradiction because there's a gap of measure at least $\epsilon$ between $U = V \cap S$ and $U' = V' \cap S$, but the gap between $V'$ and $V$ is less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Or in full algebra:
$$
\frac{\epsilon}{2} > \mu(V' \setminus V) = \mu((V' \setminus V) \cap S) + \mu((V' \setminus V) \setminus S) \geq \mu((V' \setminus V) \cap S) = \nu(U' \setminus U) \geq \epsilon
$$

Here is some information from Fremlin's textbook Measure Theory to give you a more general overview of what is possible with $\tau$-additive measures and which assumptions were really necessary in the above proof.
The restriction of a finite $\tau$-additive Borel measure remains $\tau$-additive when restricted to an arbitrary subset $S$, i.e. it is not necessary for $S$ to be measurable - 414K
The above proof fails for $\tau$-additive finite measures defined on $\sigma$-algebras that are coarser than the Borel $\sigma$-algebra (i.e. that don't measure all open sets) - 414Y(c)
The above proof fails for infinite $\sigma$-finite measures. Fremlin has constructed a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$, a locally finite $\tau$-additive $\sigma$-finite Borel measure $\mu$, and a closed set $C \subseteq X$ with $\mu(C) = 1$ such that $\mu|_C$ is not $\tau$-additive - 419A (Fremlin does not define $\mu$ on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, but on a $\sigma$-algebra containing all the open sets, and the above properties carry over to the restriction of $\mu$ to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.)

Could you please tell me why $\mathcal{V}$ is upward-direct? I know that for any $V,W\in \mathcal{V}$ there's $Z\in\mathcal{V}$ such that $(V\cup W)\cap S\subseteq Z\cap S$. But I can't find $Z\in\mathcal{V}$ such that $V\cup W\subseteq Z$.

@rfloc Take $Z' = V \cup W \cup Z$. Then $Z' \cap S = Z \cap S$, so $Z' \in \mathcal{V}$, and $V \cup W \subseteq Z'$.
